Create dynamic fields and apply validation in angular
I have this sample object
[
    {
        "labelName": "Name",
        "inputType": "textbox",
        "inputValues": "",
        "mandatory": "yes"
    },
    {
        "labelName": "Email",
        "inputType": "textbox",
        "inputValues": "",
        "mandatory": "yes"
    },
    {
        "labelName": "address 2",
        "inputType": "textarea",
        "inputValues": null,
        "mandatory": "yes"
    },
    {
        "labelName": "City",
        "inputType": "dropdown",
        "inputValues": null,
        "mandatory": "no"
    }
]

through which i need to generate form controls

ts:

FormGroup: FormGroup;
 this.fieldsData.forEach((ele, i) => {
 form[ele?.labelName]=new FormControl('',[Validators.required]);
 });
 this.FormGroup=new FormGroup(form);


HTML:

 <form [formGroup]="FormGroup">
        <div *ngFor="let data of fieldsData">
        <label>{{data.labelName}} </label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="{{data.labelName}}">
        </div>
        <button class="btn-submit" type="button" [disabled]="!FormGroup.valid" style="margin-top: 20px" (click)="SubmitDemo()">
            Submit
        </button>
 </form>

Here issue is i want to apply validation based on mandatory key if yes then apply validation, and if type is textbox then bind in input type='text' if dropdown bind in dropdown control.
Any solution Thanks

We can use ngSwitch in HTML to switch between input types.
We can use a ternary condition, to assign the mandatory based on the condition.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="FormGroup">
            <div *ngFor="let data of fieldsData">
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="data.inputType">
              <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
                <select name="cars" id="cars">
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"><textarea [formControlName]="data.labelName"></textarea></ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault><input type="text" [formControlName]="data.labelName"></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
            <label>{{data.labelName}} </label>
            
            </div>
            <button class="btn-submit" type="button" [disabled]="!FormGroup.valid" style="margin-top: 20px" (click)="SubmitDemo()">
                Submit
            </button>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  fieldsData = [
    {
      labelName: 'Name',
      inputType: 'textbox',
      inputValues: '',
      mandatory: 'yes',
    },
    {
      labelName: 'Email',
      inputType: 'textbox',
      inputValues: '',
      mandatory: 'yes',
    },
    {
      labelName: 'address 2',
      inputType: 'textarea',
      inputValues: null,
      mandatory: 'yes',
    },
    {
      labelName: 'City',
      inputType: 'dropdown',
      inputValues: null,
      mandatory: 'no',
    },
  ];
  FormGroup!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    const form: any = {};
    this.fieldsData.forEach((ele, i) => {
      const validators = ele?.mandatory === 'yes' ? [Validators.required] : [];
      form[ele?.labelName] = new FormControl('', validators);
    });
    this.FormGroup = new FormGroup(form);
  }

  SubmitDemo() {}
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for the answer can you pls add if i want to display error message also for all the fields where mandatory is yes

@user3653474 do try it and let me know if your stuck, just want to help with issues

`<div *ngIf="(FormGroup .controls['labelName'].touched || FormGroup .controls['labelName'].dirty)  && !FormGroup .controls['labelName'].valid">
This field is required `
@Narem Murali i was trying like the above code but i have issue like how can we pass dynamic variable instead of labelName

@user3653474 try `<div *ngIf="FormGroup.get(data.labelName) as control">
 This field is required 
`